# Ansible installation folder

Tags: ansible

I have installed Ansible on Ubuntu but it has installed it in the following directory:
/home/phill/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
rather than the expected /etc/ansible.

The command I used to install it was " python3 -m pip install --user ansible"

How do I get it to install in the /etc/ansible directory?

Comment: You don't. /etc/ansible is a configuration folder, not an installation folder. The Python installation should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to "install" it to `/etc/ansible`. `/etc` is used for configuration files. You should read about the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html).

However, you can install ansible globally and create the `/etc/ansible` directory

```
sudo apt-get install ansible
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem, and I've found out that indeed, if you wish to enable the configuration files globally, you might create the `ansible` directory, inside `/etc`.

```bash
cd /etc
mkdir ansible
```

Then, for example, if you want to set up the hosts for Ansible, use a text editor (like Nano or Vim) to create the `hosts` file, and then fill the information you need.

```bash
sudo touch hosts
sudo nano hosts

This kind of configuration is relegated to the user.
```